# Is it possible to create a borderless UWP application?

Tags: c#, uwp

In WPF, we can set `WindowStyle` to `None` to create a "borderless" window.

But, I found that UWP contains pages only.

Is there any way to have borderless windows in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do the same, however you could make your app go fullscreen or expand its content into title bar so you'll get more place for the content. Another similar thing may be using Picture In Picture mode, but these windows are always above others AFAIK.

Read more about fullscreen in UWP for example [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gianlucb/2015/10/18/uwp-windows-10-app-windows-startup-size-and-full-screen/), about expanding the content into title bar [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/10/20/how-to-place-custom-xaml-content-in-the-windows-universal-apps-title-bar/) and about the PIP mode [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/).

Comment: Thanks, the fullscreen mode works.  But the title bar is still there :(  guess I have to live with it.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot completely hide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see:[CompactOverlay mode – aka Picture-in-Picture – Universal Windows App Model](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/)

The first is check whether it can support.

```
 ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsViewModeSupported(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay)
```

And then you can enter it.

```
bool modeSwitched = await ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterViewModeAsync(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay);
```

The code in github:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews