# Window with rounded corners WinUI 3

Tags: c#, uwp, rounded-corners, winui-3

I need the rounded corners in my UWP(WinUI 2) application, but how I understand, it is impossible. So I found github issues, that says what WinUI 3 allows you to create a rounded corners on windows(like in new windows search). Maybe someone can help me with this?

Comment: Please link to the issue so we can see the context.

Comment: This question is about WinUI, it is recommended to ask it in [GitHub-issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues).

Comment: @Faywang I don't believe GitHub issues should be used to ask "how do I" questions?

Comment: Show some code and a screenshot of the sample, setting `CornerRadius` on controls usually does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On controls that support it, all you need to do is set the `CornerRadius` property. How to use styles to set this throughout your application is explained in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/rounded-corner

How to set this on individual controls specifically is documented here: [Control.CornerRadius Property](https://d)

```xml
<Button Content="Button" 
        CornerRadius="15" />
```

```xml
<Border BorderThickness="5"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        CornerRadius="15" />
```

You can easily see this in action in [Xaml Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/xaml-studio/9ntls214tkmq)

[image: XamlStudio Corner Radius Demo]

> If you are asking if setting this property on a Page is directly supported, I think the answer is *not yet*. I have not seen any documentation to suggest that it is.
> See: [Creating chromeless, non-rectangular Windows from UWP](https://stefanwick.com/2018/12/19/creating-chromeless-non-rectangular-windows-from-uwp/) or [Is it possible to create a borderless UWP application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134809/1690217) for possible workarounds.